Conditional list assignment in azure pipelines
How by condition I can populate list in azure pipeline yaml?
${{ if eq(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], variables['var-1']) }}:
my-list:
- element 1

Currently the above example works, but I need to have multiple values populated base on different conditions. I would expect something like this to work, but it does not:
my-list:
${{ if eq(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], variables['var-1']) }}:
- element 1
${{ if eq(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], variables['var-2']) }}:
- element 2
${{ if eq(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], variables['var-3']) }}:
- element 3

Or is it possible to do it with script and assign it to a variable that is array of strings, and then set this variable to my-list

Is there any error? Or the list doesn't contain all the elements you expected?

Please note that variables have string values - for arrays or complex objects you need to use parameters.


I need to have multiple values populated base on different conditions.

The method you expect should be achievable. You need to change the formatting and indentation of your expressions.
Here is an example:
my-list:
- ${{ if eq(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], variables['var-1']) }}:
  - element 1
- ${{ if eq(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], variables['var-2']) }}:
  - element 2
- ${{ if eq(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], variables['var-3']) }}:
  - element 3

In this case, the value will populate base on different conditions.


Or is it possible to do it with script and assign it to a variable that is array of strings, and then set this variable to my-list.

Yes, you can consider to set variables in scripts.
For example, I can use the following yaml to set a variable named my-list based on the $(Build.SourceBranch) value.
trigger:
- none

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:
- powershell: |
    if ("$(Build.SourceBranch)" -eq "var-1") {
      Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=my-list;isOutput=true]- element 1"
    }
    elseif ("$(Build.SourceBranch)" -eq "refs/heads/main") {
      Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=my-list;isOutput=true]- element 2"
    }
    elseif ("$(Build.SourceBranch)" -eq "var-3") {
      Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=my-list;isOutput=true]- element 3"
    }
  name: setVarStep

- powershell: |
    Write-Host $(setVarStep.my-list)


Test result:
When I build against main branch, the $(setVarStep.my-list) is - element 2. Now you can use the variable in your list.

